# download file using angular 2 (client) mvc api (server)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, angular, download

I need help please.
I have to download files using angular 2.

In the server side I have the following method

```
[HttpGet]
  public HttpResponseMessage Download(int id)
    {
      var url = @"\\\\srv\\temp\\201589.zip"
      var fileInfo = new FileInfo(url);
      using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
      {
         using (FileStream file = new FileStream(fileInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
         {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
            file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
            ms.Write(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);

            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
            httpResponseMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes.ToArray());
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.Add("x-filename", fileInfo.FullName);
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileInfo.FullName;
            httpResponseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

            return httpResponseMessage;
           }
           return null;
        }
    }
```

what should I do at the client side in order to sownloading the file in the same window, so user will see it at the bottom bar of the browser (not in new window or tab)

```
  let params = new URLSearchParams();

  params.append("id", 1);

  this.http.get("serverUrl/Download", {search: params}).subscribe((data: any) => {});
```

Thank you

Comment: What happens if you add only `<a title="Click to download" href="serverUrl/Download">`, without any js code. It is worked for me, my controller returned:  `var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StreamContent(myStream)
            };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            return result;`

Comment: Try this `<a title="Click to download" href="{{getResourceUrl()}}">`, and within angular component create proper url with params, or if you have url as property of object you can use  `<a title="Click to download" [href]="obj.url">`

Comment: But the download will be in another tab/window no?

Comment: In my case it was in the same window

Comment: in which browser? in my case the download is open in a different tab

Comment: I tested it in Chrome and IE

Comment: ok I got it! but the problem is that I cannot unzipped the file :( does any one knows how to download zip file?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984491/download-file-from-mvc-5-to-angular-2/41986269#41986269

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I created a shared component with hidden iframe that gets src so the file will be downloded...