# AspNetCore Mvc always returns a JSON object

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, blob, angular6

I faced out with an issue in Asp Net Core.

I can not return a file as blob data, but not as JSON object with encoded content to base64.

Here my code in C#:

```
[Route("DownloadExcel")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<FileContentResult> DownloadExcel([FromBody] Queries.In.Pages.Users.ExportToExcel.InModel model)
{
    //some logic to retrieve an array of bytes.
    var filename = $"myFile_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMdd_hh_mm}.xlsx";
    return File(byteArray, "octet/stream", filename);
}
```

In Angular 6 side:

```
this.httpClient.post(url, model, {headers: headers, responseType: 'blob'} )
  .subscribe(res => {
       let blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", response], {type: 'octet/stream'});
       saveAs(blob, '111.xlsx');
   })
```

What's the result I see in my browser response tab?
[image]
and the headers:
[image]

Whats wrong in my project and how to modify it to retrieve a blob but not JSON?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using an `octet/stream` MIME type over the correct excel type `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`?

Comment: please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984491/download-file-from-mvc-5-to-angular-2 change the logic accodingly

Comment: I think it should be a Task of IActionResult return type.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core, you need to be using an IActionResult if you are sending a custom response. All other responses will be serialized (JSON by default) and sent as response body.

Refer to the answer at [File Streaming in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460198/return-file-in-asp-net-core-web-api)